# Problem using paging in Buzz API?

Tags: api, rest, google-buzz

I am using Buzz REST API to retrieve all the buzz public updates from 1-08-2011 to 28-082011 and my query term is 'lokpal'. I need to get all the updates that people did about this topic or any other activity with tag 'Anna Hazere'. I have prepared the URL that is:

```
    REST GET URL
    https://www.googleapis.com/buzz/v1/activities/search?key=AIzaSyD7O9D4uEFyEexRPtxaU1fCsh0yu5leum4&q=lokpal+date%3E2011-07-31+date%3C2011-08-28&alt=json&max-results=100&safe=medium

where %3E refers to '>'  and %3C refers to '<' .
```

Can someone suggest me how to apply paging property to this and also retrieve all the updates that happened ion public stream. I am already able to get the activities in JSON format but want all the public updates.

Refer:http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html

Answer (score 0):

Within the body of the response is a `links` structure. One of the links is the `next` link, which is the URL for page 2. In your case, that would be:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/buzz/v1/activities/search?q=lokpal+date%3E2011-07-31+date%3C2011-08-28&alt=json&max-results=100&c=100
```

Comment: So is it there for all the responses till there are surplus results?